# Infiniband P_Keys and the Linux kernel

Tags: linux, infiniband, mellanox

I'm trying to configure Infiniband partitions between two Debian based Linux hosts running the 4.15 kernel and A Mellanox SX6036 switch. I've setup a "DMZ" partition on the swich using a PKey of `0x0001` and added the `Port GUID` numbers from the active IB connection of both Linux hosts (which happens to be `ib1` on both of them).

[image]

From what I've read [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/infiniband/ipoib.txt), and [here](https://community.mellanox.com/s/article/howto-configure-ipoib-networks-with-gateway-and-multiple-pkeys) I now run `echo PKEY_VALUE > /sys/class/net/ib1/create_child` on both hosts and I should get a new interface named `ib1.PKEY_VALUE`. I can then assign a private IP address to the new interfaces and communicate between the hosts which are members of the MY_PKEY partition. Is that how it's supposed to work?

In the example at the kernel.org link they use `0x8001` which works fine on the Linux end and creates an interface named `ib1.8001`. The Mellanox switch however won't let me set the PKey to that value. I get an error: *Invalid Pkey 0x8001. Value must be between 0x1 and 0x7fff*. I've tried different PKey values on the switch (like `0x0001`) but Linux always creates the interface prefixed with `0x8...`  which I cannot use for a PKey on the switch. Have I misunderstood something here?

---

**UPDATE**: Hoping some extra info may help. Listing the link info for both host1 and host2 along with output from `ibnodes` (results in the same output on both hosts), `ibstat` (same output aside from GUIDs) and `ibdiagnet`. When I assign an IP to the `ib.8001` interface, `dmesg` on host1 shows this:`ib1.8001: P_Key 0x8001 is not found`

I'm adding a new screenshot of the current partition since I've changed it to include *Full* membership for all Port-GUIDs.
[image]

```
host1# ip link sho
24: ib1.8001@ib1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 4092 qdisc pfifo_fast state LOWERLAYERDOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 256
    link/infiniband 80:00:02:1f:fe:80:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:02:c9:03:00:10:df:5a brd 00:ff:ff:ff:ff:12:40:1b:80:01:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:ff:ff

host2# ip link sho
16: ib1.8001@ib1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 4092 qdisc pfifo_fast state LOWERLAYERDOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 256
    link/infiniband 80:00:02:1e:fe:80:00:00:00:00:00:00:e4:1d:2d:03:00:e0:88:02 brd 00:ff:ff:ff:ff:12:40:1b:80:01:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:ff:ff

host2# ibnodes
Ca      : 0xe41d2d0300e08800 ports 2 "MT25408 ConnectX Mellanox Technologies"
Ca      : 0x0002c9030010df58 ports 2 "MT25408 ConnectX Mellanox Technologies"
Switch  : 0xf452140300823b60 ports 36 "MF0;msx6036:SX6036/U1" enhanced port 0 lid 1 lmc 0

host2# ibstat
CA 'mlx4_0'
    CA type: MT4099
    Number of ports: 2
    Firmware version: 2.34.5000
    Hardware version: 0
    Node GUID: 0xe41d2d0300e08800
    System image GUID: 0xe41d2d0300e08803
    Port 1:
            State: Down
            Physical state: Polling
            Rate: 10
            Base lid: 6
            LMC: 0
            SM lid: 1
            Capability mask: 0x0251486a
            Port GUID: 0xe41d2d0300e08801
            Link layer: InfiniBand
    Port 2:
            State: Active
            Physical state: LinkUp
            Rate: 40 (FDR10)
            Base lid: 2
            LMC: 0
            SM lid: 5
            Capability mask: 0x0251486a
            Port GUID: 0xe41d2d0300e08802
            Link layer: InfiniBand



host2# ibdiagnet
Loading IBDIAGNET from: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ibdiagnet1.5.7
-W- Topology file is not specified.
    Reports regarding cluster links will use direct routes.
Loading IBDM from: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ibdm1.5.7
-I- Using port 2 as the local port.
-I- Discovering ... 3 nodes (1 Switches & 2 CA-s) discovered.


-I---------------------------------------------------
-I- Bad Guids/LIDs Info
-I---------------------------------------------------
-I- No bad Guids were found

-I---------------------------------------------------
-I- Links With Logical State = INIT
-I---------------------------------------------------
-I- No bad Links (with logical state = INIT) were found

-I---------------------------------------------------
-I- General Device Info
-I---------------------------------------------------

-I---------------------------------------------------
-I- PM Counters Info
-I---------------------------------------------------
-I- No illegal PM counters values were found

-I---------------------------------------------------
-I- Fabric Partitions Report (see ibdiagnet.pkey for a full hosts list)
-I---------------------------------------------------
-I-    PKey:0x7fff Hosts:2 full:2 limited:0

-I---------------------------------------------------
-I- IPoIB Subnets Check
-I---------------------------------------------------
-I- Subnet: IPv4 PKey:0x7fff QKey:0x00000b1b MTU:2048Byte rate:10Gbps SL:0x00
-W- Suboptimal rate for group. Lowest member rate:40Gbps > group-rate:10Gbps

-I---------------------------------------------------
-I- Bad Links Info
-I- No bad link were found
-I---------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------
-I- Stages Status Report:
    STAGE                                    Errors Warnings
    Bad GUIDs/LIDs Check                     0      0     
    Link State Active Check                  0      0     
    General Devices Info Report              0      0     
    Performance Counters Report              0      0     
    Partitions Check                         0      0     
    IPoIB Subnets Check                      0      1
```

Answer (score 0):

InfiniBand partition keys use the highest bit (0x8000) to designate whether or not the host is a full member of the partition. Limited membership means that the host can only communicate with full members of the partition, while full members can communicate with both limited and full members.

In your case, try setting the partition key in the switch to 0x1 and set the hosts to full membership.

Comment: I've setup the Linux interfaces as ib.8001 and switch PKey is 0x1 (which gets converted to 0x0001 when I click [Apply]). I've reset the Partition to default `Full` membership (have added some info to my original post above). The hosts show  LOWERLAYERDOWN for the ib.8001 interfaces. Is this indicative of anything? Should I be able to ICMP ping between both hosts? Thanks for taking the time to look at it.

Comment: I'm not sure. I believe the "P_Key 0x8001 is not found" warning indicates that the SM hasn't configured that pkey on that node.